# Can I replace a column with values that are in a text file (space delemited) with values that are in a np.array

Tags: python, numpy

I am not a programmer, I am new to python, and I have a lot of difficulty with text files.

The columns are in a text file (.txt space delimited). Can I replace the values in the second column (DLT) with the values that I have in a numpy array?:

```
  JDAY          DLT         ELWS         T2
   4.0          5.0          6.0        7.0
   3.0          4.0          5.0        6.0
   3.0          5.0          7.0        6.0

data=np.array([6.0,3.0,4.0])
```

I can take the values from that column with this:

```
getvalues = np.genfromtxt('file.txt', skip_header=2, names=True)
val=getvalues['DLT']
```

I have been reading a lot of examples but I can´t find a solution.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. It seems that @Ophion's answer solves the problem, so please consider marking that answer as correct with the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to write:

```
getvalues['DLT'] = data
```

The caveat here is `getvalues['DLT']` must be equal in length to `data`.